# React Material tabs orientation change in responsive?

Tags: reactjs

How change React Material tabs orientation change in responsive? I'm using React Material version 4

I need `orientation="horizontal"` in responsive in desktop it should be `orientation="vertical"`

My Code:-

```js
<Tabs
                    orientation="vertical" // this need to change in responsive
                    onChange={handleTabsChange}
                    scrollButtons="auto" 
                    value={currentTab}
                    variant="scrollable"
                    className={classes.profileTabs}
                  >
```

Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get my Tab component to change its orientation value based on screen size by utilizing useMediaQuery and the useTheme hooks as shown below:

`import { useMediaQuery } from '@mui/material';`

`import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';`

Inside my component but before the render/return
[image]

Then in my Tabs component inside the orientation attribute
[image]

The only caveat is that you need to change the flex-direction of the Box/Container that holds your tabs and its panels.

By default flex boxes are set to row, so in order for your panels to render under your newly horizontally situated tabs you need to update the flex direction to column

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-responsive](https://github.com/yocontra/react-responsive) to use the `useMediaQuery` hook, and conditionally render horizonal or vertical orientiation based on screen width.

```js
// or whatever breakpoint you want to set
const smallScreen = useMediaQuery("(max-width: 768px)");

return(
<Tabs
   orientation={smallScreen ? "vertical" : "horizonal"} 
   onChange={handleTabsChange}
   scrollButtons="auto" 
   value={currentTab}
   variant="scrollable"
   className={classes.profileTabs}
>
)
```

Comment: displaying this error : 'useMediaQuery' is not defined

Comment: even I'm using this : import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery'

Comment: Looks like you're using an old version of the library and idk how it works. Here's some more recent documentation: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-use-media-query/

You can also find some light implementations of the hook online and use the code directly.

Comment: There's a typo in 'horizonTal'